# How to use 3rd party JS library with SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5, papaparse

Hello Im trying to use the PapaParse library to read content from a csv file into an array. Im not sure how to use the library in my controller. I added the papaparse.min.js folder in my project and defined it in my controller but it still doesnt work. Could anyone provide some advice on what I should do to get a 3rd party library like this to work wit a UI5 app?

I followed this tutorial step by step but cant seem to get it to work --> https://blogs.sap.com/2017/04/30/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-modules-in-sapui5/

```js
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "cap/trn/Amar_Billing/libs/papaparse"
], function (Controller, PapaParse) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("cap.trn.Amar_Billing.controller.Home", {
        
        onInit: function () {
            this.oRouter = this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter();
        },
        
        
        handleUploadFile: function(oEvent) {
            //var that = this;
            var oFileToRead = sap.ui.getCore().byId("fileUploader").getFocusDomRef().files[0];
            
            PapaParse.parse(oFileToRead, {
                download:true,
                header: true,
                skipEmptyLines: true,
                complete: function(results){
                    console.log(results);
                }
            });
        
    });
});
```

```html
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" 
                        xmlns="sap.m"
                        xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form"
                        xmlns:u="sap.ui.unified">
      <u:FileUploader
                                    id="fileUploader"
                                    uploadUrl="upload/"
                                    tooltip="upload your billing request"
                                    uploadComplete="handleUploadComplete" />
                            <Button text="Upload File"
                                    press="handleUploadFile" />
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

[File structure of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2nwg.png)

[Error in console when pressing upload button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9bAi.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `PapaParse` in your controller is `undefined` because PapaParse doesn't use the same module architecture like UI5. This is also mentioned in your linked article.

The global variable is named `Papa`, so try calling `Papa.parse`.

It's important that the global name and the imported name are different, otherwise the import will overwrite the global with `undefined`.

```js
/* global Papa:true */

sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "cap/trn/Amar_Billing/libs/papaparse"
], function (Controller, PapaParse) { // Use any name for your lib here (but not the name of the global variable)

    Papa.parse(...); // Use the global variable here.

});
```

Comment: Just a sidequestion, from where i do know which variable i have to set global? e.g Papa, but why?

Comment: It's usually part of the documentation of the library: https://www.papaparse.com/ The samples all use `Papa.someMethod`

Comment: Thank you. Adding the global variable helped!

Comment: @aharr22 Please consider accepting this answer in order to let others know that your issue is resolved with this solution.